# Exceed capacity of String when working with Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql-server, database, pivot

I have walked one round on some sites and see that the (only) way to solve Dynamic Pivot is to store the query as a string, then execute that string query. But, in my case, I seem not to be able to apply this solution because the number of columns exceed the capacity of one string.

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max)

select @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(name)
from table1
```

Although I declare maximum capacity for @columns, it is still not enough space and causes error. 
Is there any way to work around this case, or how can I build a dynamic pivot without storing query as a string?

Answer (score 1):

If your column names contains only English letters then try **Varchar(MAX)** instead of Nvarchar(max)

Varchar(max) can hold up to 2B of data while Nvarchar(max) can hold only 4k characters

Comment: Thanks. But, my column is established from name of uses registered on my site. When the number of user is enormous, perhaps I cant store it in a string :(.

Comment: maximum columns can be created for a table in sql server 2008 is 1024. I think varchar(max) would be good enough.  Also i would suggest you to redesign the table structure

Comment: I created about 700 users, and varchar(max) doesnt fulfill.It's not relative to the structure, I use dynamic pivot to create a report file.

Comment: Varchar(max) can hold 2^31 characters.. thats is around 21 million column names , assuming each column name has got around 100 characters.. I dont know then why its not holding 700 column names .. am I/u missing something ?

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. It worked properly, although the speed was not good:(. Btw, thanks your suggestion.